# mousewheel plugin not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, mousewheel

I've been using brandon aarons mousewheel plugin and is working on webkit browsers HOWEVER it doesn't work on firefox.

this was the original code for brandon aaron's which is great on webkit

```
$('body').on('mousewheel', function(event, delta){
  this.scrollLeft -= (delta*30);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

so i switched to http://cobbweb.me/blog/2012/03/30/jquery-mousewheel-plugin-version-2/
which is supposed to work on firefox, tried the code which is this

```
$('body').on('mousewheel', function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY){

  event.preventDefault();
});
```

I tried to put the scrollLeft in there with deltaY replaced and DOMMouseScroll or  MozMousePixelScroll but still to no avail. How do I make this work to bind on mousewheel so that my page scrolls horizontally on firefox?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [scrollLeft on body not working in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004186/scrollleft-on-body-not-working-in-firefox)

They fix it with changing `$('body')...` to `$('html, body')...`

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by handling the DOM events yourself (with *and* without the plugin).

Like so:

```
$('body').on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll', function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

You can see it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7PSyn/1/) (tested in Chrome and Firefox).

However, `scrollLeft` and `scrollTop` do not seem to work in Firefox (in either jQuery or basic JavaScript). See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7PSyn/3/) (should output "5"; does so on Chrome, but spits out "0" on Firefox).

Comment: yes it works with the plugin. logs proper values. I think the problem is with the scrollLeft... when i pass any delta value in firefox it doesnt work at all. it logs proper any delta values. so question is, how do i bind it to scroll horizontally (scrollLeft) and work on firefox?

Comment: also firefox doesn't seem to compute delta*number... hmm why? it just returns NaN. webkit does fine

Comment: Actually, it seems the issue you're facing has to do with `scrollLeft` and `scrollTop` not working in Firefox. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7PSyn/3/) spits out "0" in Firefox, "5" in Chrome. This would be a bug for Mozilla, if it's not already in their queue.

Comment: As for `delta*number`, output the values of both. If they're both numeric (which I doubt), one may be a string.

Comment: It's possible Firefox is receiving some botched `delta` value? This does seem very much like a Firefox bug of some kind.

Comment: well hopefully they sort it. just puzzled. oh well, i suppose i just need to standby. further investigate tomorrow when i've slept O_O Thanks eric!

Comment: Interesting, your site example runs, but when I add to my page it says `TypeError: $(...).on is not a function`

Comment: @TomBrito Older versions of jQuery do not support `$(...).on()`. I believe it was introduced in 1.7.

Comment: @Eric thanks! It worked when I changed to the google version of jquery :)

Answer (score 0):

Try: (1) event 'mousewheel', (2) function(event), and (3) use event.deltaFactor * event.deltaX to detect the scroll distance.

Check https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel, very short section "Getting the scroll distance".